# BluetoothSocket.Connect() throwing IOExceptio

Tags: android, bluetooth, ioexception

I am new to android and currently working on a bluetooth application. I have to discover and pair device which i have done successfully. After that I have to share a file with a paired device. 
Problem arises when bluetoothSocket.connect() is called. It throws IO Exception "service discovery failed" in 2.3 and "read-failed-socket-might-closed in 4.0 and above. i tried upto 4.3. My code is:

```
private void sendDataToPairedDevice(String message ,BluetoothDevice device){       
byte[] toSend = message.getBytes();
BluetoothSocket socket=null;
OutputStream mmOutStream=null;
try {
    socket = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(getUUID());
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e("", "IOException during creating socket::: "+ e.getMessage());
}catch (NullPointerException e) {
    Log.e("", "NPE Exception during creating socket::: "+ e.getMessage());
}
bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
CheckBlueToothState();
try {

    socket.connect();
    mmOutStream = socket.getOutputStream();
} catch ( IOException e ) {
    Log.e( "Bluetooth Socket", "IO Exception" );
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch ( NullPointerException e ) {
    Log.e( "Bluetooth Socket", "Null Pointer " );
}

try{
    if(mmOutStream==null){
        mmOutStream = socket.getOutputStream();
    }
    mmOutStream.write(toSend);
}catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e("", "IOException during write::: "+ e.getMessage());
}catch (NullPointerException e) {
    Log.e("", "NPE Exception during write::: "+ e.getMessage());
}
```

}

```
private UUID getUUID(){
    String android_id = Secure.getString(getApplicationContext()
            .getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);
    Log.i("System out", "android_id : " + android_id);

    final TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getBaseContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

    final String tmDevice, tmSerial, androidId;
    tmDevice = "" + tm.getDeviceId();
    Log.i("System out", "tmDevice : " + tmDevice);
    tmSerial = "" + tm.getSimSerialNumber();
    Log.i("System out", "tmSerial : " + tmSerial);
    androidId = ""
            + android.provider.Settings.Secure.getString(
                    getContentResolver(),
                    android.provider.Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);

    UUID deviceUuid = new UUID(androidId.hashCode(), ((long) tmDevice
            .hashCode() << 32)
            | tmSerial.hashCode());
    return deviceUuid;
}
```

}

```
private void CheckBlueToothState() {
if( bluetoothAdapter == null ) {
    Log.e("","Bluetooth NOT supported" );
} else {
    if( bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled() ) {
        if( bluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering() ) {
            Log.e("", "Bluetooth is currently " +
                    "in device discovery process." );
        } else {
            Log.e("", "Bluetooth is Enabled." );
        }
    } else {
        Log.e("", "Bluetooth is NOT enabled" );
        Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent( BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE );
        startActivityForResult( enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT );
    }
}
```

}

I am getting IO Exception at socket.connect(). I searched a lot on google and stackoverflow, but none of solutions worked. Most of solutions were not to use hardcoded UUID which i am not hard coding. 
Any help will be highly appreciated.